# Flutter remove SafeArea padding whitespace color

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I am unsuccessfully trying to remove the `SafeArea` padding from the top and bottom of `settings_ui` Flutter package. Has anyone encountered the same issue? How do you respectfully add padding around the `SettingsList` component to the device safe area so this whitespace would not appear? Changing the Scaffold background colour did not help much, as this is the padding.

```dart
  Widget buildMobileLayout() {
    return SafeArea(
        child: SettingsList(sections: [
      SettingsSection(
        title: const Text(
            'Please select your region'),
        tiles: countries.map((region) {
          int index = countries.indexOf(region);
          return SettingsTile(
            title: Text(region.title),
            leading: Text(region.flag),
            trailing: selectedIndex == index
                ? const Icon(Icons.check_circle_rounded,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 229, 228, 237), size: 24.0)
                : null,
            onPressed: (context) {
              setState(() {
                selectedIndex = index;
              });
              updateRegion(region.code);
            },
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    ]));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffF2F2F7),
        body: Scaffold(
            body: Responsive(
                desktop: buildMobileLayout(), mobile: buildMobileLayout())));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: how about remove the `SafeArea` widget? or replace `SafeArea` with `Padding`?

Comment: @Zhentao, this results in the same, same as using the `SizedBox` with height